# How to make bypass insert failed objects in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, batch-insert

In one of my project, Entity Framework in used.

I came across a situation where performance is terrible. When there are multiple records that need to be inserted into a table one by one, about **50 ~ 500** not very sure but very huge.

At first, I used:

```
dbcontext.Adds.Add(alist);
```

to do the insert. But soon I found out once there exist even 1 object that is has invalid data and could not insert into database correctly, none of the data could be inserted! All data related to each other and could not bypass any incorrect ones.

Here is my solution:

```
foreach(var a in alist)
{
    //...
    try
    {
        dbcontext.Adds.Add(a);
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // just log and bypass one by one
        log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("NOTSAVE").Info(a.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now, it works properly.

But there is a big issue that the performance is terrible! Client may wait for several seconds for each action. And custom feed back is also worse.

Does anyone know any other solution to improve performance? It's better to complete in 500ms ~ 1second. But now once the records > 100 it may cost more than 1 second **each time**. Obvious and frequent pause with customer each operate via UI as the result.

Comment: You can use `AddRange` and then anylize exception, to exclude particular invalid item, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The First and important thing you can do is turning off `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`, it has huge impact on performance.

```
dbcontext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
foreach(var a in alist)
{
    //...
    try
    {
        dbcontext.Adds.Add(a);
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // just log and bypass one by one
        log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("NOTSAVE").Info(a.ToString());
    }
}
dbcontext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

read this article for more info: [EntityFramework Performance and AutoDetectChanges](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/entityframework_performance_and_autodetectchanges/)

You can use third party libraries:

- [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)
- [EntityFramework.Utilities](https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities)

and you can use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` in`ADO.NET` which is really fast.

Comment: Thank you so much, after adding dbcontext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; I tested the time cost less than half as previous situation.